# Webgl not working on firefox

Tags: firefox

I'm using firefox installed with snap. My current version is 72.0.1, I have `webgl.force-enable: true` and `webgl.disabled: false`.

Going to https://codesandbox.io/ is not working and I get this error in the js console:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.
```

As long as I remember I've never been able to get WebGl working on firefox with elementary. Did someone made it?

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

That is because of snap version ...I don't have it also but I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS...with normal version of firefox no problems at all...